# in a long time [AE vs BE]

Tags: prepositions, transatlantic-differences

> I haven't seen Ben **in** a long time. I wonder if he's still alive
> and kicking.

[From E-DIC, which is an English-Japanese dictionary.]

**Question:** Is **in** correct in British English?

I suspect that **in** is American English. I suppose that native speakers of British English would use "for" instead of **in**.

Comment: **In** is certainly not _incorrect_ in Br. E., though I personally would use **for** and would regard **in** as typically American.

Comment: 'In a long time' may be more common in US English, and 'for a long time' in British English, but both are acceptable in either kind of English.

Comment: And speakers of AmE would use **for** as well as **in**.  Same speaker could use either. But "We *wait* for a long time", not "in a long time".

Comment: I agree with what Kate and Michael said.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to do with "correct" English, and there's certainly no *semantic* difference. Here's [the American English usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seen%20them%20in%20a%20long%2Cseen%20them%20for%20a%20long&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=10) for the past century...

[image]

...and here's the corresponding [British English chart...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=seen%20them%20in%20a%20long%2Cseen%20them%20for%20a%20long&year_start=1919&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=10)

[image]

As you can see, Anglophones both sides of the pond have been shifting from ***for*** to ***in*** at an accelerating pace. But no-one would really take any notice of which preposition you used.